# Is there a way manage mysql package string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

```
const creatUser = "INSERT INTO users(`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`password`) VALUES(?)"; 
const checkRegister = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ";
```

So I have a big project include a lot of mysql query .
And mysql package use string store query, Is there a way to handle multiple string in node js?
like put them all into one file, I try the import fs package then read the file ,but it does a lot of job than I expect?

Comment: I won't add more than the first answer given as far as a solution to the way you are approaching the problem- but I would encourage you to consider an ORM. There are plenty of them that provide features like that for reusable queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still apply your idea to write all queries into one file, then use the `fs` module to read them back.

Assuming that you have a file called `queries.sql` with a  semicolon `;` separator between the values:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const queries = fs.readFileSync('queries.sql', 'utf8')
  .split(';')
  .filter((query) => query.trim().length > 0);

console.log(queries);  // ["SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'john@example.com'", "INSERT INTO users(...) VALUES(...)"]
```

the rest should be simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just create a POJO (or multiple POJO's, grouping queries by something, like the purpose of the queries) object with the queries.  Then you just require the file.

#### user-queries.js

```js
module.exports = {
    query1: "select * from users",
    query2: "select * from users where id=?"
    ...
};
```

Then, whenever you need user queries, you just require the above.

```js
const userQueries = require('./user-queries.js');

// Now you can do userQueries.query1, for example.
```

### On in ES Modules

#### user-queries.js

```js
export default {
    query1: "select * from users",
    query2: "select * from users where id=?"
    ...
};
```

Then:

```js
import userQueries from './user-queries.js';

// Now you can do userQueries.query1, for example.
```